# Line break instead of newline

Tags: r, non-ascii-characters

Is there an alternative to `\n` to split text onto a new line?  `\n` creates a new paragraph, which can inherit extra spacing.  A line break method would ensure next line was same paragraph - equivalent to `Shift + Enter` in Word.  Does it exist as a programmatic character?

I've tagged R below, but the question seems equally valid for Python etc.

Comment: Is this rmarkdown or simply text printing in R? The latter seems to work fine (i.e. with no spaces) on the console `cat('this is a \nnew line')`.

Comment: `?Quotes` shows a list of the available escaped characters.

Comment: @lmo Yes I've tried `\r` but it shows in graphical plots as a non-printable character (box with a cross)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the general case of flow documents, [in theory](http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/) line breaking is very complicated with [different characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode). In practice, applications or operating systems usually represent a newline with one or two control characters. For example Excel uses [*Left Feed*](https://unicode-table.com/en/000A/) or (as long as I know) word uses [Vertical Tab](http://web.archive.org/web/20080325092316/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/59096) to break. Therefore, there is no general rule in your case and it is completely application specific. In other words, you should not expect to generate a string, feed it to different environments and expect them to behave similarly.

Comment: You might get more sophisticated answers if you change the tag of your answer.